# MyCraft - Info to download?

Tags: games

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my sons computer, then through Ubuntu Software Center purchased MyCraft.  I received an email confirmation of the purchase, but no Product Key or download information.  How do I get and install this?

Comment: search for mycraft in the dash, ubuntu logo icon top left

Answer (score 1):

You can download it for free at http://www.michaelfogleman.com/craft/